# list_display with a function, how to pass arguments?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, argument-passing

The [Django admin docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) says that it is possible to specify a callable as a value that can be used in `list_display`. If I need to pass some extra context to the function via function arguments, what's the best way to accomplish that?

In pseudo code, what I'd like to do is something like:

**App realestate:**

models.py:

```
class A(models.Model):
    raw = models.TextField()
```

admin.py:

```
from utils import processing

list_display = [processing('realestate app result', True)]
```

**App party:**

models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    raw = models.TextField()
```

admin.py:

```
from utils import processing

list_display = [processing('party app result', False)]
```

**utils.py:**

```
def processing(obj, short_description, allow_tags=False):
    def process(obj):
        # do something
        pass
    process.short_description = short_description
    process.allow_tags = allow_tags

    return process(obj)
```

Comment: you cannnot pass arguments this way, the cell should know how render itself based on the model it represents. what argument do you need to pass? describe your situation and we will see you should solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not specify the `short_description` and `allow_tags` inside the function itself.

define processing like this:

**utils.py:**

```
def processing(obj):
      #do something
      pass
```

on each ModelAdmin class, do:

```
class RealestateAdmin(...):
   list_display = [processing,]

   def processing(obj):
       return utils.processing(obj)
   processing.short_description = 'realestate app result'
   processing.allow_tags = True


class PartyAdmin(...):
   list_display = [processing,]

   def processing(obj):
       return utils.processing(obj)
   processing.short_description = 'party app result'
   processing.allow_tags = False
```

So you have one place (utils.py) which contains the logic.
And every class defines the properties to display in the table.

Comment: Define the `process` function is not required then.